# IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio not working on MAC

Tags: macos, cplex, ibm-ilog-opl

I just downloaded the latest version of IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio for mac (Scholar version), I managed to install it but when I open it it only shows a blank white window . Does anyone know a solution to this problem? Thank you
I'm on MACOS Big Sur and I downloaded IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio V20.10 for OSX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigSur is not yet supported but you may try to get the beta that supports BigSur as said in [this link](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datascience/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=4969f0e5-367b-44e0-a679-a7e4f46e8a9a&CommunityKey=ab7de0fd-6f43-47a9-8261-33578a231bb7&tab=digestviewer#bm4969f0e5-367b-44e0-a679-a7e4f46e8a9a):

> The fix for BigSur is ready as a beta - please drop a mail to cos-ai-support@wwpdl.vnet.ibm.com with your academic email, and I will send you a download link.

Comment: I will send an email to get the beta version .Thank you